# Most efficient way to add images to a body wrapper?

Tags: html, css

So I know how to effectively add color wrapping to a body, such as webkit-box-shadow.

But this time I want to add images to my solid background as wrapping around my body. A good example is a sky blue background with random clouds surrounding your body div. Is there anyway to do this aside from just creating a background image that syncs up with your body perfectly?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoLR.png

Big thanks to anyone who can lend any kind of advice!

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far? Show us your code and what are you now..

Comment: Random and css does not work. To get random images you either need random class names or the server gives you random images under one URL (perhaps via redirect)

Answer (score 0):

As with many things in HTML, you can achieve this in various ways. What I would do, would be to create a transparent image with clouds, and set that as the background-image of the parent div.

Example CSS:

```
#wrapper { width: 1000px; background: url('clouds.png') center top transparent; }
#inner { background: #FFF; width: 940px; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 6px; }
```

Example HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
    ...Your page contents...
  </div>
</div>
```